# Kotlin: why would you want to convert Int.toString?

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm still new to kotlin so take my question with a grain of salt

so i've been learning about kotlin and in one of the articles i was reading about had this code as an example of how to use .toString

```
val sum1 = { a: Int, b: Int -> 
    val num = a + b 
    num.toString()   //convert Integer to String 
} 
fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
    val result1 = sum1(2,3) 
    println("The sum of two numbers is: $result1") 
}
```

Output:

```
The sum of two numbers is: 5
```

as i understand it, it's a "5" but of type string.. but why??

we can just simplify the code and get the same outcome:

```
    val sum1 = { a: Int, b: Int -> a + b }

    val result1 = sum1(2,3)
    println("The sum of two numbers is: $result1")
```

output:

```
The sum of two numbers is: 5
```

so.. i've seen examples of how to use it, but i still didn't find anything to explain why you'd want to use it

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call toString because the string templating implicitly calls them for you, but what happens when you specifically need it as a string? Like the difference between "1" + 0 and 1 + 0, or storing into a string variable, or when you want to process it as a string such as enumerating each character etc

Comment: Note that changes the type of `sum1` from `(Int,Int) -> String` to `(Int,Int) -> Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everyone talking about "how you can use it" but still no one saying "why you'd want to use it"

so i've made an example that hopefully will help people

```
fun main(){
    inference()
}

fun inference() {
    val sum1 = { a: Int, b: Int ->
        val num = a + b

        // convert Integer to String
        num.toString()
    }

    val result1 = sum1(2, 3)
    println("The sum of the two numbers is: $result1")


    // compiler error: can't use "result1" because it's a String and not an Int
    //val result2 = sum1(result1, 3)


    // let's say your code only takes strings but you want to insert an Int
    val sum2 = {a: String, b: String ->
        val str = a + b
        str
    }

    var int: Int? = 10
    //int = null // uncomment this line to get the other outcome
    if(int != null){
        val result3 = sum2("the number we got is: ", int.toString())
        println(result3)
    } else {
        val result4 = sum2("we did not get any number, ", " check if int is null")
        println(result4)
    }
}
```

hope this helped someone

Answer (score 0):

`.toString()` returns a string representation of the object.
It is not just restricted to converting `Int` to `String`.
You can use it to convert other data type like `Boolean` to `String`.

So whenever a a developer need to store `Int` as a `String`, he/she can cast Int to String with the help of `.toString()`.

The above code snippet shared by you is way generic, hence you got confused.

To summarize, whenever you want to store/map any data-type into String, then use `.toString()`.